# Does Nextra produce static files that I can manually upload to my website?

Tags: next.js

I created a simple blog template using Nextra, which is a nextjs static site generator: https://nextra.vercel.app/get-started

I ran:

```
yarn build
```

But when I look at the folders, I don't see where the statically generated files are stored.
I want to generate the static files, and then upload them to my website manually.

Is this possible?

**Update**

I ran this command:

```
yarn next build && yarn next export
```

error:

```
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - using build directory: /home/blank/dev/git/vercel-app-blog/.next
info  - Copying "static build" directory
info  - No "exportPathMap" found in "next.config.js". Generating map from "./pages"
Error: Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`.
  Possible solutions:
    - Use `next start` to run a server, which includes the Image Optimization API.
    - Use any provider which supports Image Optimization (like Vercel).
    - Configure a third-party loader in `next.config.js`.
    - Use the `loader` prop for `next/image`.
  Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-image-api
    at /home/blank/dev/git/vercel-app-blog/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:257:23
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/blank/dev/git/vercel-app-blog/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Can you try running `yarn next build && yarn next export`?

Comment: @brc-dd updated my question with the error I got...

Comment: `next/image` component with default `loader` doesn't work on statically exporting HTML. You need to use the regular `img` tag or a custom `loader`. Refer the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features

Comment: @brc-dd so my blog build fine using vercel, I guess they are doing this internally?

Comment: Vercel by default doesn't use static HTML export. When you run `next build` it will generate a `.next` folder that is used when you do `next start` without doing a `next export`.

Comment: BTW, you can also use packages like next-images or next-optimized-image. A whole lot of discussion is here - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18356

Comment: @brc-dd not sure what .next folder is, but I would think vercel generates static files to servce as its faster, and not actually run a nodejs server to service the static pages ... maybe I misunderstood what .next folder does etc.

Comment: The answer to your doubt is how Vercel serves your pages. They use an "edge network" instead of running a node.js server, which does the job of "routing requests to the correct Serverless Function or Static File output of your Builds". So basically, running `next build` generates a `.next` directory. Vercel then uploads the build artifacts (`.next` and some more config, public files, etc.) to their edge network, and serve the static files directly. Any dynamic request is handler by serverless edge functions. And, for speed they heavily cache the assets.

Comment: References - https://vercel.com/solutions/nextjs, https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#optimized-for-nextjs, https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/overview